# MongoDB / PyMongo return documents that match another document grouping

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I've got two collections in MongoDB:

1. Vehicles
2. Tests

Tests contains scores for assessments, which includes a property "_vehicle_id"

I need to return all vehicles that have scored higher than 70 (stored as an int) in at least 3 of their last 5 tests (using the property "unit_score").

I've read about subdocuments, sort, limit, etc, but I'm stumped how to achieve this in Mongo alone.  So far my efforts have been to retrieve the last 5 results for all people, then iterate over in Python, but this is massively inefficient when I'm working with potentially 10,000 tests every 30 seconds...

So I'm looking for a way for MongoDB/PyMongo to ONLY return the Vehicle documents which have had more than 3 matches where unit_score > 70.

I currently have the following code, which returns the ObjectId() of each matching vehicle, but I would like it to instead return the Vehicle object for each match:

```
db.tests.aggregate([
{ "$match" : { 'statuscode' : '404', 'datetime' : { "$gte" : "2013-11-22 15:05:35" } } },
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$_vehicle_id", "count" : { "$sum" : 1 }}},
{ "$match" : { "count" : { "$gt" : 3 } } }
])
```

The date will be dynamic (for the last x minutes), but it's static now for test purposes.

I've looked at "$project", but I'm not sure if this is right for returning the associated object.  _vehicle_id is a bson ObjectId(), so I was hoping it would be as simple as db.vehicles.find_one("$_vehicle_id"), but I fear not...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at using [`aggregate`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate)?

Comment: I've not, @JohnnyHK... Reading up on aggregate, I assume this would be used to find my Tests criteria, group by _vehicle_id, SUM my matches, and then return the list of _vehicle_ids.  Is there a way for this to return the actual unique Vehicles in one query?  Thanks :)

Comment: Or would it be better to use MapReduce?

Comment: You need to explicitly bring any fields you want included in the final output along through each stage of the aggregation pipeline.  `aggregate` is typically much faster than map-reduce so you definitely want to avoid using map-reduce for this if possible.

Comment: That's great thanks @JohnnyHK.  I'm grasping the concept and am playing with it in Python Shell now.  I've just discovered "$gte" and "$lte", which I think is the final piece of the jigsaw...

Comment: I've extended my questions @JohnnyHK, if you don't mind taking a look for me?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB has no support for joins, so a single MongoDB query (whether `find` or `aggregate`) can only access the documents in a single collection.

So in this case you'd have to follow up your `test.aggregate` call that gets the vehicle ids with a `db.vehicles.find({_id: {$in: vehicle_ids}})` query to get the vehicle docs for those ids where `vehicle_ids` is an array of ids you build from the `aggregate` results.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for my requirements, as if I understand correctly, $first only reveals the properties of the first item of the group, which would be an instance of Test, not Vehicle, therefore without "color" and "model" being part of the Test document, we wouldn't be able to access Vehicle's properties as we cannot traverse between objects in the aggregation.  I hope I'm wrong?

Comment: @KarlM.W. Sorry, my bad, I misunderstood your question.  See updated answer.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @JohnnyHK. That's the outcome I was leaning towards from my own investigations, but hoped there was a more streamlined way.